# Launch an executable from within a windows file watcher service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a file watch service, written in C#, that I need to launch an application when it detects the file drop. I am using notepad as a test application to launch. The file watcher is working fine, but I cant get notepad to launch. Any assistance with what I am missing would be great.

Code that fires when the file drop is detected:

```
public void FileCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs inArgs)
        {
            Process LaunchApp = new Process();
            LaunchApp.StartInfo.FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppStartPath"];
            LaunchApp.Start();
           // Process.Start(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppStartPath"]);
            Log.WriteLine(" File added: " + DateTime.Now + " " + inArgs.FullPath);
        }
```

Path reference from the app.config:

```
<add key="AppStartPath" value="Notepad.exe"/>
```

I also tried:

```
<add key="AppStartPath" value="C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe"/>
```

Comment: Does `Process.Start("notepad.exe")` work for you?

Comment: "a file watch service": is it a Windows Service, or simple an activity inside an interactive application?

Comment: Typically a service runs in a different user context than your desktop. Have you checked task manager to see if the process is running in a different user context?

Comment: @Luaan - It did not work either.

Comment: @Richard - It is a service that is installed as a service.

Comment: @StingyJack - You are right, it is running. Is there a way to have it launch for the user to use?

Comment: If its something a user needs to use (like a reminder app), then perhaps a windows service isn't the right technology choice.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a file watch service,

Services run in a separate security context to processes in a user logon session.

This can be seen if you add the Session ID column to Task Manager's Processes tab, or – better, in Process Explorer.

Any processes the service launches will run in the service's own context: not the user. There are very good security reasons for this.

To perform interactive operations from a service you need a per user agent that is run in the user's context. Typically the service listens on a named pipe and the user agent is run from the startup group (or Run key in the registry). The agent connects to the named pipe and can respond to requests from the service (or the service from the user agent).